# Charts.js listando dados de um BD (ionic 3)

Tags: ionic

Boa tarde a todos, estou estudando o ionic e gostaria de representar alguns dados que estão em um BD no meu gráfico. Fiz o listar via api de php e os valores estão chegando todos certos(inclusive utilizei o ngfor para lista-los), porém não sei como fazer para transformar os dados do bd em um array. Segue os códigos: (Listar no .html)

```
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let produto of mesa">
<ion-item >
  <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-8>
          {{produto.potencia_atual}}  
      </ion-col>
  </ion-row>


</ion-item>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

page.ts

```
 grafico(){
  this.consumoProvider.grafico()
  .then(data => {
    this.mesa  = data;

  });
}
```

page.ts na parte da representação da label:

```
{
    label: 'Meu terceiro Dataset',
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 00, 00)',
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointRadius: 1,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: (????),
    scanGaps: false,
  }
]
}
```

A onde "(????)" Seria o nome da variável array.

Comment: Só para deixar claro, o select da api é esse: select potencia_atual from consumo_atual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para fazer esse select na variável mesa você pode utilizar map para obter um array apenas com o campo potencia_atual e usá-lo na configuração do seu gráfico.

```
this.terceiroDataset = this.mesa.map(x=>x.potencia_atual);
```

Comment: Funcionou cara! Muito obrigado!